# Azure removing subscription creator from account

Tags: azure

Our former boss set up as PAYG sub on azure on his own azure account rather than the dev admin account. Hes no longer with us. If I remove him has owner will that interrupt or cause trouble with the subscription in any way? I have added the dev account as owner role now too.

Just paranoid if I remove him it will cause some kind of issue and bring the service down as he was the original creator of it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a billing/admin support issue, and not something answerable here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, you are not allowed to change the "Account" admin directly from Azure portal. However, you can change the Account admin by creating Azure Support Ticket.

**Note:** Azure Support ticket for Subscription management is **free of cost**.

[image]

For more details, refer to [Create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).